# Only non div elements show in a single line , inside parent div

Tags: html, html-table

My HTML code:

```html
        <div style="background-color:rgb(81, 205, 50); display:inline-table; width:700px; height:150px; border: 2px solid black; padding: 2px;">
              <img src="../rail_logo.png" width="150" height="150" style="margin-left: 20px; display:table-cell; border: 1px solid black;">
              <img src="../indian-railways.jpg" width="150" height="150" style="border: 1px solid black; display:table-cell;">
              <img src="../pm-railway.jpg" width="150" height="150" style="border: 1px solid black; display:table-cell;">
              <div width="150" height="150" style="border: 1px solid black; display:table-cell;"></div> <!--From here on, the divs appear in the next line (one below the other). Why?-->
              <div width="150" height="150" style="border: 1px solid black; display:table-cell;"></div>
        </div>
```

---

Upon executing the above code, all the `<img>` elements appear in the same line except for the last `<div>` which appears in the next line.

**My output:**

The divs should appear in the positions shown by the red highlighter
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: you missed a closing div tag

Comment: Oh sorry, typing mistake

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. This also includes using `display: inline-table` or `display: table-cell` This was acceptabe in 1990, but not nowadays. Use flexbox and grid to create layouts.

Comment: When I click Run code snippet (even full page), it shows each image in its own line, and the divs on the right, next to one another. What browser are you running this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to get the layout like you want. For example:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: green;
}

.img-box,
.hr-box {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.hr-box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 55px;
}

.hr-box:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="img-box">
  <img class="img-box">
  <img class="img-box">
  <div class="img-box">
    <div class="hr-box"></div>
    <div class="hr-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are separate boxes for CSS and HTML in the snippet editor, and a Tidy button that will indent your code.

Comment: I want the last two divs to be one below the other horizontally

Comment: @Abhishek But the structure must be the same? Or it's okay to wrap the last two divs?

Answer (score 0):

You can put 2 smaller photos inside the div with "inline-block" display.

Or you can use the [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html) plugin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).